# What does budgie chirping means?

Tags: sound, budgerigar

I have an 5-years old Budgie (male, unfortunately now is alone) in a cage.

I recognize when he's singing (for example when play with bell or hearing some sounds he likes). I also recognize when he wants to eat or drink (buckets are almost always full but when I'm all day outside and while he's hungry he chirps in particular way when I got home).

Yesterday he started chirping like when he's hungry but I noticed that he has food and water. But I'm sure that he wants something.
What does it mean?

Comment: It sounds like he recently lost a friend, if this is true how long ago did he is friend leave/die?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could describe the behaviour more. Or perhaps post a video of it. There are a great many reasons why birds vocalize, and it's hard to say which is the answer without more information.

Answer (score 2):

Chirping could mean many things, mourning for a friend, hungry, or just wants your companionship. He could even be communicating with birds outside

Comment: OK, but he's chirping only when I am at home, so maybe he wants my companionship. It's very strange, but he stopped chirping when I cleaned up my room, indeed.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the answer to my question and it wasn't obvious. My budgie doesn't like the "mess" in my room. When I cleaned up my room, he stopped chirping. :)

Comment: Can I ask, why I have here down votes (both on question and answer), when the answer is indeed truth?

Comment: What do you think

Comment: I don't know. It was my observation for weeks, so I wrote conclusions I noticed. It's been a month from the "cleaning" (setting books on the shelves, segregating papers) and budgie doesn't chirp now in that way.

Comment: The right way to test that is to perform the cycle multiple times. Get your room messy again. See if he starts chirping. Clean your room. See if he stops chirping. Get the room messy and clean again. And again and again. Do this at least 10 times. You got downvotes because we know a budgie's chirping has nothing to do with room cleanliness.